# Emulate simple javascript (location.href=) with Mechanize for Python

Tags: javascript, python, mechanize

short: How to execute/simulate javascript redirection

```
location.href="http://www.site2.com/";
```

with python Mechanize?

I've made a python script with mechanize module that looks for a link in a page and follows it.

The problem is on a particular site that when I do

```
br.follow_link("http://www.address1.com")
```

he redirects me to this simple page:

```
<script language="JavaScript">{                                                                                         
    location.href="http://www.site2.com/";                                                                                           
    self.focus();                                                                                                                   
    }</script>
```

Now, if I do:

```
br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())

... #other code

br.follow_link("http://www.address1.com") 
for link in br.links():   
br.follow_link(link)
print link
```

it doesn't prints anything, that means that there is no link in that page.

But if I manually parse the page and I execute:

```
br.open("http://www.site2.com")
```

Site2 doesn't recognizes that I'm coming from "www.address1.com" and the script does not work as I would like!

Sorry if it's just a newbie question and thank you in advance!

Comment: *that means that there isn't such link in that page.* No it doesn't, it means that `link` is a string object.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, corrected, my head is melted.

Comment: Solved here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881423/mechanize-python-how-to-follow-a-link-in-a-simple-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
br.set_handle_referer(True)
```

after the constructor call.

I recommend you these options :

```
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
```