# Mechanize + Python: how to follow a link in a simple javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, mechanize, referer

short: How to execute/simulate javascript redirection with python Mechanize?

```
location.href="http://www.site2.com/";
```

I've made a python script with mechanize module that looks for a link in a page and follows it.

The problem is on a particular site that when I do

```
br.follow_link("http://www.address1.com")
```

he redirects me to this simple page:

```
<script language="JavaScript">{                                                                                         
    location.href="http://www.site2.com/";                                                                                           
    self.focus();                                                                                                                   
    }</script>
```

Now, if I do:

```
br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())

... #other code

br.follow_link("http://www.address1.com") 
for link in br.links():   
br.follow_link(link)
print link
```

it doesn't prints anything, that means that there is no link in that page.
But if I manually parse the page and I execute:

```
br.open("http://www.site2.com")
```

Site2 doesn't recognizes that I'm coming from "www.address1.com" and the script does      not work as I would like!

Sorry if it's just a newbie question and thank you in advance!

p.s. I have br.set_handle_referer(True)

EDIT: more info:
Inspecting that link with Fiddler2 it looks like:

> GET http://www.site2.com/ HTTP/1.1 Host: www.site2.com Connection:
>   keep-alive User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko)        Chrome/22.0.1229.94
>   Safari/537.4 Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Referer: http://www.address1.com Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>   Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3 Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=6e161axxxxxxxxxxx; user=myusername;
>   pass=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; ip=79.xx.xx.xx;
>   agent=a220243a8b8f83de64c6204a5ef7b6eb;
>   __utma=154746788.943755841.1348303404.1350232016.1350241320.43; __utmb=154746788.12.10.1350241320; __utmc=154999999; __utmz=154746788.134999998.99.6.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=%something%something%

so it seems to be a cookie problem?

Comment: Quick check, you aren't mechanizing this to abuse some referral bonus?

Comment: Do the URLs change or are they always the same?

Comment: No, I'm not abusing any referral. Moreover: the address in "location.href"doesn't change, but the other one yes. Short: www.site2.com is static, www.address1.com is dynamic. Thank you for answers!

Comment: Cool that means you won't have to scrape `site2`'s URL out the Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! in this way:

```
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)

    ...

    br.follow_link("www.address1.com")
    refe= br.geturl()
    req = urllib2.Request(url='www.site2.com')
    req.add_header('Referer', refe)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj) )
    f = opener.open(req) 
    htm = f.read()
    print "\n\n", htm
```

Comment: So it was a cookie problem?

Answer (score 1):

Mechanize can't deal with JavaScript, since it can't interpret it, try parsing your site manually and passing this link to, `br.follow_link`.

Comment: follow_link() wants an Absolute_Url as parameter, so it seems that I can't simply do something like br.follow_link("http://www.google.com") thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the HTTP referrer header explicitly before making your request

```
br.addheaders = [('Referer', 'http://alpha.com')]
br.open("http://beta.com")
```

More details in the surprisingly difficult to find official docs  http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html

Comment: This seems to be the way to go. But it doesn't work. I've added more info at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
br.open("http://alpha.com") 

br.follow_link("http://beta.com")
```

If you use `br_follow_link` hopefully that sets the HTTP referrer with the previous page. Whereas if you do`br.open` that's like opening a new window, it doesn't set the HTTP referrer header.

---

**Edit**. Ok it looks like `.follow_link` doesn't take strings but takes a special `mechanize.Link` object with a property `.absolute_url`. You can fake that.

```
>>> class Fake:
...     pass
...
>>> x = Fake()
>>> x.absolute_url="http://stackoverflow.com"
>>> br.follow_link(x)
<response_seek_wrapper at 0x2937af8 whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at 0x2937f08 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x02934970>>>
>>> br.title()
'Stack Overflow'
```

or make a real `mechanize.Link` which is less hacky but more tedious.

Comment: follow_link() wants an Absolute_Url as parameter, so it seems that I can't simply do something like br.follow_link("http://www.google.com"). But anyway really thank you for the answer!

Comment: Shucks, it _ought_ to work like that. Have another idea (see edited answer)

Comment: It doesn't works as needed. In fact, it works simply like br.open, so site2.com doesn't see that I come from address1.com